# Checking if a router is online or offline?

Tags: networking, security, denial-of-service

Recently I've been receiving ddos attacks to my router, for educational purposes, I want to know how the attacker is finding out when my router has been ddosed.

They said they are doing something to do with ping? Can someone tell me what they are doing and how they check if the ddos took my internet offline?

Comment: Are you taking about a home router or in a office?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a simple home/small office router with decent connectivity (which seems to be what you are describing) - a DDoS instructs a large number of systems to try overload your router with traffic.   Thus in order to detect how successful it is it can look at how your router is responding.

Your router most likely responds to (some variant(s)) of ping.  Ping works by sending a packet of data, waiting for a response and timing it, thus it possible to roughly discern what is happening with the remote router - the following would be common results from which conclusions can be drawn:

- Router stops responding to all pings ( It has been knocked offline )
- Router responds to a few pings, but lots of dropped packets (Router is either flooded with too much traffic or is unable to process packets, resulting in slow - probably unuseable performance - partial success !)
- Latencies of packets are varying wildly (The link is getting flooded, so things will be going slow for the people using it).

"Ping" can also be used to attack your router - by sending packets which your router responds to it can co-opt both incoming and outgoing bandwidth - depending on the type (there are multiple different ways to do pings), its possible to send large packets and get them back, consuming your bandwidth.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing you need for a DDoS attack is to get the router to respond.

If they ping your IP Address and the router says: Hey, I'm here, pinging you back, then the attacker knows you exists.

If they then flood your connection with so many packages that your router crashes and they then send a ping, the router is not responding, so the ping times out.

If it were a real-life situation, it would be as follows:

An attacker walks up to you and says: Hey, how are you? You respond with something. Can be "fine", "ok" or whatever.

The attacker then beats the crap out of you and says: "Do you want me to stop?" If you reply with anything: "yes" for example, the attacker knows you are still conscious. They continue to beat you until they think you are unconscious. They ask again, and you don't respond anymore, they know they reached the goal.

So basically, they have a method to check if your router is up and running or not. It is possible they do a port-scan and instead of pinging the router directly with an IMCP packet (ping request) they can ping one of the ports and the router simply relays that packet to one of the devices behind the network. Port 80 and 443 are common ports to be open or forwarded. If the router crashed, it will not forward ports anymore either.

That said, commercial routers are very smart and can detect when traffic is supposed to be a DDoS attack. If they detect one, they will block incoming traffic (ignore it) that matches the kind of traffic generated for that DDoS attack. To the attacker it seems they are succesful when they really are not. They can use services like VPN to connect from a different IP address to test if their attacking IP was blocked or not.

There are other methods to perform a DDoS attack, but for the scope of this answer to this post, all you need to know is that the method is the same. If the attacker can make your router respond, they will be able to test if their attack is succesful or not.

Comment: Small clarification: While blocking incoming traffic from one IP address is simple in a DoS attack, Distributed DoS comes from multiple IPs which makes it more difficult to detect and block.

Comment: @RobbieW. true, but then you are talking about a datacenter router, not a home-consumer router. But I'll edit the answer accordingly. I just felt it was slightly off-topic because the question is: how does an attacker knows if their attack worked, not how does a DDoS work.

Comment: Also, can anyone explain the downvote?